# Discrepancy between function arguments in actual crash and core dump

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

I'm investigating a `SIGSEGV` using gdb. This is the last stack frame as seen by gdb attached to the running process about to crash:

```
#0 0x08d1805c in FooBar (this=0xa9315578, dt=0.100000001)
```

At that point, I've saved the state using `generate-core-file`. When I then inspect this dump with gdb, the same stack frame reads:

```
#0 0x08d1805c in FooBar (this=0x0, dt=2.69049305e-42)
```

This confuses me. On the one hand, the value `0.1` for `dt` in the live situation makes sense. On the other hand, `this` being `0x0`, as seen in the dump, would nicely explain the `SIGSEGV`.

More importantly, how could there be a discrepancy at all?

Comment: Probably core dump was truncated when it was generated.

Comment: @ks1322 Wouldn't that show as missing values, or al 0, as opposed to random numbers?

Comment: if address of "this" resides in shared memory between two processes or mmaped memory of some driver it can change between what gdb sees before and after of generate-core-file command.

Comment: I would assume that this question is obsolete already

Comment: @sunil While this question is no longer relevant to me, if you're sure your comment is correct, you could post it as an answer and score some rep :)